# Angular 13 - Getting error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getParsed')"

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular13

working on an Angular 13 project and getting an [exception:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCfiu.png)

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getParsed')
> at .../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:325924
> at Array.filter ()
> at nd._getActiveElements (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:325808)
> at nd.handleEvent (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:325525)
> at Object.afterEvent (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:326752)
> at Fe (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:152333)
> at Au._notify (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:256447)
> at Au.notify (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:256268)
> at ta.notifyPlugins (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:275524)
> at ta._eventHandler (.../main.2506c840be361c93.js:1:276188)

I searched for occurrences of ".getParsed" in the entire application but there are no results. Same with node_modules. Hopefully someone here as encountered this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable value exist, Check before errored line. Like below

```
let abc = null;
if(abc){
 /* Execute code */
}
```